# Low hdd IOPS - should I be worried?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I have been having issues with a pc that's randomly losing power. Ever since, I've been finding new ways to stresstest everything to try and find a way to force the power loss in order to be able to debug it. (Still haven't found it).
Today, I got a lot of disk errors before the crash, according to windows logs. (Bad sectors). However, scanning it didn't turn up anything.

Anyway, this prompted me to install burnintest and test my harddrives. Now, the results are kind of awkward:

[image: Screenshot of IOPS]

The disk pointed out by windows would've been disk `E:`. This happens to be the oldest disk I have, and as you can see, it doesn't even reach half of the operations speed that faster disks do.
*on an important note:* All disks except for `C:` are 7500RPM harddrives. (`C:` is an SSD)

You can clearly see that `H:` (also an older disk) also doesn't even reach half of what `G:` and `I:` reach. It's important to note that disk `I` is ~1 year old and G is only 2 weeks old. It would be no surprise to me that the IOPS drop after time, but my question is, **how much should these (extremely low) results worry me?**

**small update:** This screenshot was taken after 11 minutes. After 20 minutes, the difference kept about the same % ratio

Comment: Better install the free version of [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) and examine the information it has for the disks that had disk errors. Best would be to post the results for us as screenshots (although there is a lot of information).

Comment: @harrymc I ran it, it says everything's good. I agree that screenshots would be *a lot* of info.

Comment: Everything is probably alright. But if you wish to be sure, scan the disks using the trial version of [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/), to see if it comes up with any bad sectors (this could take a long time). Afterwards, run chkdsk.

Comment: Already done so. No bad sectors.

Comment: Then you are good to go, but step carefully.

Comment: @harrymc You should post some kind of informative answer so I can give away my bounty. It'd be a waste to throw it away

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An episode of disk errors is certainly a reason for worrying,
but here are some answers for the question "should I be worried?"
(for classical disks which are not SSD).

- A good program to check the current state of the disk is [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy).
  Examine well the data found in the "Storage" section, and especially
  the S.M.A.R.T data.
- Verify the integrity of the system data of the disk by running `chkdsk`.
- To be sure of the disk, one can reformat it (not using quick format).
  This will rewrite all sectors and flag the ones that are bad.
  All data is lost, but this can resuscitate the disk.
  Better redo afterwards the above two checks of the disk, just in case,
  and if errors are found then further use of this disk is not recommended.

Even if a disk that had errors now passes all the tests, it should still be
treated with suspicion. Good backups are a must after such an episode.